# iOS - How to link tabs with specific view controllers in storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I am an iOS storyboard newbie. I have a problem linking specific tabs with specific ViewControllers. I have 3 tabs, when I hit the second one, it goes to the third view controller, and when I hit the third, it goes to the second view controller. Is there a way I can ensure which tab shows which view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a problem with your indexing of the tabs and mapping them to the view controllers.  Tabs start at index 0.

So the Tab number 3 is at index 2.

Comment: how do I change the mapping in storyboard?

Comment: You can't change the mapping. The mapping is a set order starting from 0.  If you want to change the order in the storyboard, just drag them into place.